# How would you write the OGF for the sequence {hk}

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

Write the ordinary gen. function for the sequence.
So trying to work this out. I ended up with (1+x)^7. 
But I am not sure if this is correct. Thanks for any help.

[image]

Comment: that was a typo. the answer I got is (1+x)^7

Comment: $(1+x)^7$ is correct.

Comment: You are welcome.